# Why doesnt my image path find the image when it is up one directory?

Tags: html

I'm having trouble getting an image loading on my website.

When I had the "images"-folder in the same folder as my html this code managed to load the image successfully.

```
<img src="/images/progressive.jpg" width="400" />
```

However, I want to put the "images"-folder up one directory. So I move the folder and change the path to:

```
<img src="../images/progressive.jpg" width="400" />
```

but it fails to load, any idea why that is?

My vs code extension is "autofilling" the path so it recognize the file, which should mean that the path is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found the issue. I'm using the VS code extension "Live server" which seemingly can't find files up one directory. When I open the .html file from the file explorer instead of using the "Live server" the images load successfully.

Comment: this happens because your html is in the document root and you are trying to access a file "up one level" that is outside the document root. Try with a subfolder and you should see no issue on this

Answer (score 0):

Location of image defined as `/images/progressive.jpg` for current page location `https://website.com/path/subpath/page.html` will use full image address as `https://website.com/images/progressive.jpg`

But, for location of image defined as `../images/progressive.jpg` and the same page location (`https://website.com/path/subpath/page.html`) you will receive image address `https://website.com/path/images/progressive.jpg`

Maybe this is a problem?

Comment: Not sure I understand, isnt that what I want? I get this error: GET http://127.0.0.1:5501/images/progressive.jpg 404 (Not Found). This error (with the same URL) I get both if I use the first path in my question, and the second one. Somehow it doesnt seem to recognize the "../". Any thoughts?

Comment: I just found the issue. Im using the VS code extension "Live server". The image was not loaded when opening the website with this extension, however if I open the HTML-file from the file explorer, it does load. So the problem seem to be with the extension. Thank you for your time!

Comment: @Jalpster, It would be very nice if you describe the cause of your problem as an answer. In order to help other people with the same problem.